# is something wrong with sympy solve method or latex parser?

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to convert latex expression to sympy form and then solve it. 
When I feed the output of the parser(or converter actually?) to solve method, it finds no solution. However, if I manually enter the parser generated expression, it finds the roots successfully. What is wrong with parse_latex ( most probably ) or solve method?
Thanks in advance. Here is the code sample you can try:

```
    from sympy import*
    from sympy.parsing.latex import*

    x = Symbol("x", real=True)
    sym_eqn = parse_latex("|x-2|-1") 
    print sym_eqn #  Abs(x - 2) - 1
    print type(sym_eqn) # <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>
    print type(Abs(x - 2) - 1) # <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>
    print solve(Abs(x-2)-1)  #  [1,3], which is ok
    #print solve(sym_eqn) # NotImplementedError: solving Abs(x - 2) when the argument is not real or imaginary.
    print solve(sym_eqn,x) # []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root issue here is whether or not your symbol 'x' has an attribute "real" set to `True`, or not.
Consider the following two symbols:

```
a = Symbol('x',real=True)
b = Symbol('x')
```

`a` and `b` are not of the same type and in fact `a==b` is `False`.

What happens when you execute

```
sym_eqn = parse_latex("|x-2|-1")
```

is that that `sym_eqn` is now an expression that contains a `Symbol` that does not have the attribute `real` set to `True` which is required to run `solve` on it.

Having understood this, the question is now how to get `parse_latex` to return an expression that would contain a `Symbol` that is `real`?

The only way I found is to write a function that recursively traverses the expression's tree and rebuilds a copy of it such that the result is the same, except all `Symbol`s are now `real`.

```
def rewrite_expr_real(expr):
    res_list = []

    if isinstance(expr,Symbol):
       return Symbol(str(expr),real=True)

    if not expr.args:
        return expr

    for a in expr.args:
        res_list.append(rewrite_expr_real(a))

    return expr.func(*tuple(res_list))
```

Now,

if you rewrite your code as follows:

```
sym_eqn = rewrite_expr_real(parse_latex("|x-2|-1"))
```

The rest of your code will work as you expect it.

Comment: Thank you. I got the issue. This worked. I also tried y = Symbol("y", real=True)
sym.subs(x,y) workaround but it didn't work and I am curious about, why?

Comment: it is ok now. I should have written sym = sym.subs(x,y) instead, since sym is not mutable itself. Thanks, though..

Answer (score 0):

Yakov's answer is on point, but I'd like to offer a code snippet that converts all symbols to "real" in a single substitution.

```
from sympy import symbols

expr = expr.subs((str(symbol), symbols(str(symbol), real=True))
                  for symbol in expr.free_symbols)
```